# Profile is created but there are no apps associated in DataWedge Zebra TC25

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, intentfilter, datawedge

I am working on Zebra TC25 devices, trying to create a profile using DataWedge API's programmatically. The profile is created and I tried to scan a barcode but nothing happens So I checked my DataWedge App(version 7.0.4), I went inside my profile and checked there are no Associated apps. I have a sample code which works perfectly fine, the same example code applied in my working project it doesn't work. If anyone could help will be great time saving. Posting my code down here please have a look.

DatawedgeManager.kt

```
class DatawedgeManager(val context: Context) {

private val dwInterface = DWInterface();



companion object {
    @Volatile
    private var instance: DatawedgeManager? = null
    const val PROFILE_NAME = "DataWedgePf"
    const val PROFILE_INTENT_ACTION = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
    const val PROFILE_INTENT_START_ACTIVITY = "0"


    fun getInstance(context: Context): DatawedgeManager? {
        return instance ?: synchronized(DatawedgeManager::class.java) {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = DatawedgeManager(context )
            }
            return instance
        }
    }

}




private fun createDataWedgeProfile() {
    //  Create and configure the DataWedge profile associated with this application
    //  For readability's sake, I have not defined each of the keys in the DWInterface file
    dwInterface.sendCommandString(context, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_CREATE_PROFILE, PROFILE_NAME)
    val profileConfig = Bundle()
    profileConfig.putString("PROFILE_NAME", PROFILE_NAME)
    profileConfig.putString("PROFILE_ENABLED", "true") //  These are all strings
    profileConfig.putString("CONFIG_MODE", "UPDATE")
    val barcodeConfig = Bundle()
    barcodeConfig.putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "BARCODE")
    barcodeConfig.putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true") //  This is the default but never hurts to specify
    val barcodeProps = Bundle()
    barcodeConfig.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", barcodeProps)
    profileConfig.putBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", barcodeConfig)
    val appConfig = Bundle()
    appConfig.putString("PACKAGE_NAME", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)      //  Associate the profile with this app
    appConfig.putStringArray("ACTIVITY_LIST", arrayOf("*"))
    profileConfig.putParcelableArray("APP_LIST", arrayOf(appConfig))
    dwInterface.sendCommandBundle(context, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_CONFIG, profileConfig)
    //  You can only configure one plugin at a time in some versions of DW, now do the intent output
    profileConfig.remove("PLUGIN_CONFIG")
    val intentConfig = Bundle()
    intentConfig.putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "INTENT")
    intentConfig.putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
    val intentProps = Bundle()
    intentProps.putString("intent_output_enabled", "true")
    intentProps.putString("intent_action", PROFILE_INTENT_ACTION)
    intentProps.putString("intent_delivery", PROFILE_INTENT_START_ACTIVITY)  //  "0"
    intentConfig.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", intentProps)
    profileConfig.putBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", intentConfig)
    dwInterface.sendCommandBundle(context, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_CONFIG, profileConfig)
    initScan()
}

fun initZebraLaserScan(){
    createDataWedgeProfile()
}

fun initScan(){

    dwInterface.sendCommandString(context, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_SCANNER_INPUT, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_SCANNER_INPUT_ENABLE)

}

fun deinitScan(){

    dwInterface.sendCommandString(context, DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_SCANNER_INPUT,
        DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_SCANNER_INPUT_DISABLE)

}
}
```

DWInterface.kt

```
class DWInterface()
{
    companion object {

    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_ACTION = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ACTION"
    const val DATAWEDGE_RETURN_ACTION = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_ACTION"
    const val DATAWEDGE_RETURN_CATEGORY = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
    const val DATAWEDGE_EXTRA_SEND_RESULT = "SEND_RESULT"
    const val DATAWEDGE_EXTRA_RESULT = "RESULT"
    const val DATAWEDGE_EXTRA_COMMAND = "COMMAND"
    const val DATAWEDGE_EXTRA_RESULT_INFO = "RESULT_INFO"
    const val DATAWEDGE_EXTRA_RESULT_CODE = "RESULT_CODE"

    const val DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_DATA_STRING = "com.symbol.datawedge.data_string"
    const val DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_LABEL_TYPE = "com.symbol.datawedge.label_type"

    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_CREATE_PROFILE = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.CREATE_PROFILE"

    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_GET_VERSION = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.GET_VERSION_INFO"
    const val DATAWEDGE_RETURN_VERSION = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_GET_VERSION_INFO"
    const val DATAWEDGE_RETURN_VERSION_DATAWEDGE = "DATAWEDGE"

    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_GET_ENUMERATE_SCANNERS = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.ENUMERATE_SCANNERS"
    const val DATAWEDGE_RETURN_ENUMERATE_SCANNERS = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_ENUMERATE_SCANNERS"

    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_GET_CONFIG = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.GET_CONFIG"
    const val DATAWEDGE_RETURN_GET_CONFIG = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_GET_CONFIG"
    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_CONFIG = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.SET_CONFIG"

    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_GET_ACTIVE_PROFILE = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.GET_ACTIVE_PROFILE"
    const val DATAWEDGE_RETURN_GET_ACTIVE_PROFILE = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.RESULT_GET_ACTIVE_PROFILE"

    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_SWITCH_SCANNER = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.SWITCH_SCANNER"

    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_SCANNER_INPUT = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.SCANNER_INPUT_PLUGIN"
    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_SCANNER_INPUT_ENABLE = "ENABLE_PLUGIN"
    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_SCANNER_INPUT_DISABLE = "DISABLE_PLUGIN"

    const val DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_SOFT_SCAN = "com.symbol.datawedge.api.SOFT_SCAN_TRIGGER"
}

fun sendCommandString(context: Context, command: String, parameter: String, sendResult: Boolean = false)
{
    val dwIntent = Intent()
    dwIntent.action = DATAWEDGE_SEND_ACTION
    dwIntent.putExtra(command, parameter)
    if (sendResult)
        dwIntent.putExtra(DATAWEDGE_EXTRA_SEND_RESULT, "true")
    context.sendBroadcast(dwIntent)
}

fun sendCommandBundle(context: Context, command: String, parameter: Bundle)
{
    val dwIntent = Intent()
    dwIntent.action = DATAWEDGE_SEND_ACTION
    dwIntent.putExtra(command, parameter)
    context.sendBroadcast(dwIntent)
}

fun setConfigForDecoder(context: Context, profileName: String, ean8Value: Boolean,
                        ean13Value: Boolean, code39Value: Boolean, code128Value: Boolean,
                        illuminationValue: String, picklistModeValue: String) {
    val profileConfig = Bundle()
    profileConfig.putString("PROFILE_NAME", profileName)
    profileConfig.putString("PROFILE_ENABLED", "true")
    profileConfig.putString("CONFIG_MODE", "UPDATE")
    val barcodeConfig = Bundle()
    barcodeConfig.putString("PLUGIN_NAME", "BARCODE")
    barcodeConfig.putString("RESET_CONFIG", "true")
    val barcodeProps = Bundle()
    barcodeProps.putString("scanner_selection", "auto")
    barcodeProps.putString("decoder_ean8", "" + ean8Value)
    barcodeProps.putString("decoder_ean13", "" + ean13Value)
    barcodeProps.putString("decoder_code39", "" + code39Value)
    barcodeProps.putString("decoder_code128", "" + code128Value)
    barcodeProps.putString("illumination_mode", illuminationValue)
    barcodeProps.putString("picklist", picklistModeValue)
    barcodeConfig.putBundle("PARAM_LIST", barcodeProps)
    profileConfig.putBundle("PLUGIN_CONFIG", barcodeConfig)
    sendCommandBundle(context, DATAWEDGE_SEND_SET_CONFIG, profileConfig)
}
}
```

ViewpagerActivity.kt

```
class ViewPagerActivity : AppCompatActivity(), onPageChangeListener, SubscribeScanner {

private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
private var listOfScreenObj = arrayListOf<String>()
lateinit var barcodeScannedEvent: BarcodeScannedEvent


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_layout)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val dataViewModelFactory = DataViewModelFactory(this)
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, dataViewModelFactory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    listOfScreenObj = mainViewModel.getScreenIds()
    setViewPager()

}


private fun setViewPager() {
    viewPager2.adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(this,listOfScreenObj)
    viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback)
}

private var pageChangeCallback = object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
       Toast.makeText(this@ViewPagerActivity , "Selected position: $position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

override fun onPageChange(position: Int) {
    viewPager2.currentItem = position
}


override fun subscribeListener(barcodeScannedEvent: BarcodeScannedEvent) {
    this.barcodeScannedEvent = barcodeScannedEvent
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    if (intent.hasExtra(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_DATA_STRING)) {
        val scanData = intent.getStringExtra(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_DATA_STRING)
        val symbology = intent.getStringExtra(DWInterface.DATAWEDGE_SCAN_EXTRA_LABEL_TYPE)
        val date = Calendar.getInstance().time
        val df = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        val dateTimeString = df.format(date)
        barcodeScannedEvent.onBarcodeScanEvent(scanData,symbology,dateTimeString)

    }
}
}
```

In my ManiFest file;

```
  <activity
        android:name=".view.activities.ViewPagerActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="app.example.dataWedge" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Since there are no associated Apps in my profile, if i scan anything it doesn't affect. So i tried adding my package manually then onNewIntent was invoked. This piece of code DataWedge Functionality is from this github ref::[DataWedgeKotlin](https://github.com/darryncampbell/DataWedgeKotlin). Attached a screenshot and am using Zebra TC25 device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like my sample? :)

This line:

`appConfig.putString("PACKAGE_NAME", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)`

Should be:

`appConfig.putString("PACKAGE_NAME", context.packageName)`

Comment: Yes I've tried the same still not working . But the sample code which i worked on still works perfectly I don't  know what am I missing here.

Comment: We tried on TC57 , initially it worked and then after two three trails even that stopped working but later we did a restart on TC57 now it's working . For TC25 devices it's still not working

Comment: In your example code, you have a single activity where you've set intent-filters and launcher which btw works fine. But for me my launcher is a different activity and my scanner activity is different .

Comment: You have: const val PROFILE_INTENT_ACTION = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
Your Intent Filter is: <action android:name="app.example.dataWedge" />
These values should be the same, are they?

Comment: Yes I've changed the intent-filter action it's same as my manifest file.

Comment: There was a problem in DataWedge App itself I've figured out and resolved the issue. Thank you so much

Comment: @nethra gowda    What was the solution?

Comment: @pdschuller I had to delete the profile & recreate a new one then it worked fine.